# ASP.NET MVC grey bar on sample layout website missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I started creating an ASP.NET (4.5.1) MVC project in VS2019 by following a tutorial. It is quite straight forward creating the HomeController and an Index View file. Files have not been changed so far. After compiling and opening in IE and FF I do not see the grey bar at the very top compared to the displayed one in the video tutorial. Instead, there is just a very small icon left to the "Application name" hyperlink but there should be a grey bar (div-element) wrapping "Application name" hyperlink and stretch from the very left to the very right.

[Screenshot how it looks on my device and web browsers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRONd.png)

[Screenshot how it should look like based on the video tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzrJ.png)

It is for sure not critical at this stage but really wondering.
Does somebody know what is maybe missing / misconfigured?

I already searched web but there are thousands of other results being displayed.

Thanks

Best regards

Comment: It looks like css/javascript assets that haven't loaded or are broken. You can investigate by opening the browser's dev tools and looking for errors.

Comment: If you want the newer bootstrap versions, you'll need to modify your client-side view code to account for the breaking changes. Since this is a fresh site, it's probably worth doing now before you build out content.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue. Bootstrap has not been installed as NuGet package. Therefore, I guess bootstrap 4 or 5 are used by default since bootstrap 3 is not supported anymore. By manually installing bootstrap 3 NuGet package, it perfectly works as expected. By updating to version 4 and 5, it breaks.